# How to print the counts for multiple columns separately from a csv file?

Tags: python, pycharm

I need to print the column name and the amount of times each value appears in it. The dataset has 6 different columns and I need it to print 3, the "Source", "Destination", and "Protocol" each in descending order. I've searched on here and all I can find is someone wanting to print only one column, I need it to print 3. Here is the [file](https://kapextmediassl-a.akamaihd.net/IST/IN300/IN300_1905A/IN300_Dataset1.csv)

I've gotten it to print all of the columns I need and a count, but I think it's printing the count for all of them together and I need a separate count for each column and I'm not sure how to get it to do that. I tried putting brackets around each header but that didn't work. This is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

unitnine_dataset = 'IN300_Unit9.csv'
unitnine_dataset = pd.read_csv(unitnine_dataset, sep=',',
                      decimal='.', header='infer')

df = pd.DataFrame(unitnine_dataset)
count = df[['Source', 'Destination', 'Protocol']].value_counts(ascending=False)

print(count)
```

Comment: is `pandas` a required component of your solution? You are on the correct path, but you want a `collections.Counter()` for each column. You can probably manage that via a dictionary.

Comment: I don't think it has to be pandas, it's just the only one I am familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with pandas count values of the column, using value_counts()

```
def count_unique_values(df, col):
    return df[[col]].value_counts(ascending=False) #count columns values

list_of_cols = ['Source', 'Destination', 'Protocol']
for col in list_of_cols:
    print(count_unique_values(df, col))
```

Comment: This worked but it printed the counts for all of the columns in the file, how do I get it to print just the 3 I need?

Comment: made the change to print only those 3 columns

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to accumulate counts via some kind of dictionary where keys are the columns you are interested in and values of individual `Counter()` objects.

Here is a proof of concept:

```py
import csv
import io
import collections

test_data = """
name,col1,col2
a,1,1a
b,2,b2
c,1,b2
""".strip()

columns_meta = {}
with io.StringIO(test_data) as file_in: ## simulare open()
    for row in csv.DictReader(file_in):
        for key, value in row.items():
            columns_meta.setdefault(key, collections.Counter())[value] += 1

for col, val in columns_meta.items():
    print(f"column: {col}")
    for value, count in val.most_common():
        print(f"\t{value}: {count}")
```

That should give you:

```
column: name
        a: 1
        b: 1
        c: 1
column: col1
        1: 2
        2: 1
column: col2
        b2: 2
        1a: 1
```